# Alias in bashrc returns syntax error

Tags: bash, arch-linux, bashrc

I am using archlinux with bash.
I have been trying to create a new alias but `bashrc` doesn't like my curly bracket. The command down below should count the video duration length of every `.mkv` in my directory (depth=3) and convert it to hours.

```
alias vidlength="find . -maxdepth 3 -iname '*.mkv' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | paste -sd+ -| bc | awk '{print(($1/60)/60)}'"
```

When I run source `$ source ~/.bashrc` and
`$ vidlength` after that, I get this error:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: {print((/60)/60)}
awk: cmd. line:1:                 ^ syntax error
```

Bashrc and stuff like that is pretty new to me, and I couldn't find any similar problems on google. Any help is greatly appreaciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with your 'curly bracket'.

You used `"` to quote the entire alias value, so within that string `$1` which you intended to mean 'field 1' in awk, is instead expanded to *shell parameter 1 at alias definition time* which was an empty value; as a result the expression `((/60)/60)` makes no sense -- you're trying to divide something by 60, but there is no something. You can quote the `$` with backslash, or you can use the trick that awk field references still work with a space in them like `$ 1` or `$ NF` while shell parameters don't.

Alternatively, use a shell function (which accepts full shell syntax) instead of an alias (which requires everything be packed into a single string):

```
function vidlength {
    find . -maxdepth 3 -iname '*.mkv' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | 
    paste -sd+ -| bc | awk '{print(($1/60)/60)}'
}
```

In addition, you can simplify this by having awk do the addition instead of a separate bc, and you don't need all the parentheses:

```
 find . -maxdepth 3 -iname '*.mkv' -exec ffprobe -v quiet -of csv=p=0 -show_entries format=duration {} \; | 
 awk '{tot+=$ 1} END{print tot/3600}'
 # I used the $ 1 syntax to allow use in alias, can use $1 in function
```